# Why do some GTK+ themes have transparency?

Tags: themes, gtk

Certain themes like the community theme "Homosapien" have transparency in particular apps such as Gnome Terminal and Gnome System Monitor. Is this a bug?

Screenshot:
http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/5165/transparentj.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature of the murrine engine that powers some themes. You only see it on applications that have support for it, such as gnome-system-monitor, unless you add the rgba module to GTK+, which honestly I don't suggest you do unless you are willing to put up with the work required to find all the incompatible programs and add work arounds.

Answer (score 1):

I think its a feature. http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2007/12/gnome-theme-engine-designer-adds-transparency-to-gtk.ars

Comment: Yes, I have no idea when this feature was implemented though. It has done this a while back in Ubuntu on some themes, and only with certain apps. I did not particularly enable rgba.

Comment: I have it enabled, so if someone wants a list of applications that need to be explicitly disabled I can post it.

Comment: Thanks, helped me out a bit, I was mildly curious about this.